# cURL: Curl is available but cannot access Facebook! (0 - ) - when using Facebook Connect

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I run wordpress sites on my domains. I am having an issue with cURL on the server side.

Basically I have tried installing multiple plugins on my sites (Some fresh installs) but they all result in the same cURL error

"cURL: Curl is available but cannot access Facebook! (0 - )"

I have asked around and some have said it is a server side problem.

If anyone has any knowledge or experience why this might be happening would be great to know.

Examples of plugins I am using (I have also tried others)

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-fb-autoconnect/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider probably has an IP filter activated.

You can issue outgoing connections only towards domains/IPs you specify in the cPanel.

You either specify the domain/IP in the cPanel or ask the hosting providers to deactivate the filter.

Comment: Thanks man, I have asked them. RIght now their response to my first question is "I have checked your files on the server and cannot see issues with file permissions, Curl is also enabled on your account. You might need to check wordpress forums and see how to fix this issues, perhaps there is special permissions you will need to set via your ftp program."